# can't change value of variable unless you do the command strcpy

Tags: c

I am reading the "C programming book" and I understand how this program functions, but, I don't understand one thing.

I don't understand how fahr is functioning as a variable.
does fahr have two values or one? Cause I thought once you write a value for a variable you can't change it unless you do the command strcpy. Maybe I am wrong, can some one help me clarify?

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float fahr, celsius;
    int lower,upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 700;
    step = 2;

    fahr = lower;
    printf("Fahrenheit\tCelsius\n");
    while (fahr <= upper) 
    {
        celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);
        printf("%3.0f \t        %6.1f\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to have a more meaningful title that actually describes your problem and I removed the c++ tag since you are asking a c programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a variable for example float fahr you define a memory space in which will be saved the number that you give to your variable. The content of the the variable fahr can change with an assignment expression such as float = lower where now the content of fahr is the same with the content of lower variable .You can assign values to a variable as many times you want. Assigning a value to a variable has nothing to do with strcpy .strcpy is a function that copies one string to another for example:

```
char src[40];

 strcpy(src, "This is a sentence ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up two different worlds my friend.

`fahr` is just a **float variable**. It means it's value can be changed if we perform arithmatic operations on it, like assignment, addition, subtraction.

On the other hand, strcpy (string copy) **copies string from character pointer to another character pointer**. It has nothing to do with your **float** variable `fahr`.

Answer (score 0):

`fahr` is just an ordinary variable.  It defines a few bytes of memory as type `float`.  In C, you can write to any variable; that's what the language is for.

> I thought once you write a value for a variable you can't change it unless you do the command strcpy.

You are probably looking at code like this

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

Here, `s` is an *array* of 6 `char`s.  It's often called "a string", but that's only a convention.  To the compiler, it's an array.

You can't say something like

```
char s2[] = s;
```

because in C you can't copy arrays by assignment.  The name of the array is associated with its starting point.  Because array-copying is commonly needed, there are functions for the purpose in the standard library, such as **memcpy**(3) and -- for NUL-terminated-strings -- **strcpy**(3).